# Handlebars if method returns null / empty string

Tags: java, handlebars.java

I currently use handlebars in java (com.github.jknack.handlebars)
and have a handlebars helper method to get a link (with some logic behind)

```
{{ getLink data.node}}
```

which just render the url /subfolder/link.html

In my handlebars template I now only want to print the url (a-tag) when the helper method returns a non empty string (e.g. there is a link available)

I tried it with

```
{{#if getLink data.node }}
     <a href="{{ getLink data.node}}">Link-Text</a>
{{/if}}
```

but no link was rendered

What would be the correct syntax for my if?

Thanks
RCX

Edit:
getLink Helper Method in LinkHelper.class

```
public CharSequence getLink(JsonObject node, Options options) throws IOException {
    String link = fetchLink(node);
    if(link != null){
        return link;
    }
    return "";
}
```

registered via

```
    HandlebarsTemplateEngineImpl.getHandlebars().registerHelpers(new LinkHelper());
```

Comment: share `getLink` `registerHelper` implementation and example for `data` object

Comment: added getLink Method and registerHelper - data is just an JsonObject available in the current context

Comment: share `fetchLink` implementation, it doesn't seems you need to register helper to accomplish that

Comment: `fetchLink` calls some external service - the link is not available before

Comment: is `fetchLink` a blocking method ? add log to print `link` afterwards, does it exist ?

Comment: yeah it's blocking - and it only use external service once, then it is cached anyway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Handlebars.java is not well documented and missing couple of unit tests (consider to contribute if this answer helped), for some reason calling nested `JsonObject` removed at [this](https://github.com/jknack/handlebars.java/commit/ddf047f#diff-c0d87ca4770448a4ed9a456524e6dd98R113) commit, you can still call nested `String`, but there is a trick with parentheses.

Full example:

```
import com.github.jknack.handlebars.Context;
import com.github.jknack.handlebars.Handlebars;
import com.github.jknack.handlebars.Helper;
import com.github.jknack.handlebars.Template;
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import java.util.Map;

public class HandlebarsJavaTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Handlebars handlebars = new Handlebars();
        Gson gson = new Gson();

        handlebars.registerHelper("getLink", (Helper<Map<String, Object>>) (jsonObject, options) -> {
            String link = fetchLink(jsonObject);
            return link != null ? link : "";
        });

        String data = "{'data':{'node':'/bla.html', 'node2':'inside node2'}}";
        // Pay attention to parentheses !!!
        // {{#if (getLink data.node)}} throws ClassCastException, java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.util.Map
        String rawTemplate = "{{#if (getLink data)}} <a href=\"{{getLink data}}\">Link-Text</a> {{/if}}";

        Type type = new TypeToken<Map<String, Object>>(){}.getType();
        Map<String, Object> map = gson.fromJson(data, type);

        Template template = handlebars.compileInline(rawTemplate);
        Context context = Context.newBuilder(map).build();

        System.out.println(template.apply(context));
    }

    private static String fetchLink(Map<String, Object> map) {
        try {
            return map.get("node").toString();
        } catch (NullPointerException npe) {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

`<a href="/bla.html">Link-Text</a>`

If node is just a string ( same output )

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Handlebars handlebars = new Handlebars();
    Gson gson = new Gson();

    handlebars.registerHelper("getLink", (Helper<String>) (node, options) -> node != null ? node : "");

    String data = "{'data':{'node':'/bla.html', 'node2':'inside node2'}}";
    // Pay attention to parentheses !!!
    String rawTemplate = "{{#if (getLink data.node)}} <a href=\"{{getLink data.node}}\">Link-Text</a> {{/if}}";

    Type type = new TypeToken<Map<String, Object>>(){}.getType();
    Map<String, Object> map = gson.fromJson(data, type);

    Template template = handlebars.compileInline(rawTemplate);
    Context context = Context.newBuilder(map).build();

    System.out.println(template.apply(context));
}
```

If you insist node is an object using `this.[data]` or `this.[data.node]` will not do the work, working example for the same output:

```
import com.github.jknack.handlebars.Context;
import com.github.jknack.handlebars.Handlebars;
import com.github.jknack.handlebars.Helper;
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.JsonObject;

public class HandlebarsJavaTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println(
            new Handlebars()
                .registerHelper("getLink", (Helper<JsonObject>) (json, options) -> {
                    try {
                        // logic here
                        return json.get("data").getAsJsonObject().get("node").getAsJsonObject().get("link").getAsString();
                    } catch (NullPointerException npe) {
                        return null;
                    }
                })
                // Pay attention to parentheses !!
                .compileInline("{{#if (getLink this) }} <a href=\"{{getLink this}}\">Link-Text</a> {{/if}}")
                .apply(
                    Context
                        .newBuilder(
                            new Gson()
                                .fromJson(
                                    "{ 'data': { 'node': { 'link': '/bla.html' }, 'node2': 'inside node2' } }",
                                    JsonObject.class
                                )
                        ).build()
                )
        );
    }
}
```

If you have time, consider to contribute to this open source by adding proper documentation or at least unit tests `{{#if (method param)}}`.

According to the [source code](https://github.com/jknack/handlebars.java/blob/master/handlebars/src/test/java/com/github/jknack/handlebars/IfBlockTest.java#L48-L53)

```
package com.github.jknack.handlebars;

public class IfBlockTest extends AbstractTest {

@Test
public void falsy() throws IOException {
    // empty string
    shouldCompileTo("{{#if value}}true{{else}}false{{/if}}", $("value", ""), "false");
```

BTW, the `#if` built-in helper will return `False` for empty string, so if `getLink` will execute `return "";` the if condition will not and the text will not be rendered, to assert this you can add `{{else}}` before the closing if `{{/if}}` and see that what is rendered.

Comment: you can say ```String link = "/bla.html";```
but the problem is the link is never displayed (it doesnt matter if i return "", null, or "/bla.html" :(
the if always evaluates to false

Comment: omg - thanks a lot - it was just the missing parentheses around the helper call ```{{#if (getLink this) }} ```